# MariaDB, Tables are listed but not found, collation is "in use"

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

In my mariadb there are three databases. Two very small ones (3 MB) with a couple of tables and one with one large table that I am entering a lof of data into for testing purposes. Currently there should be about 500.000 rows in it. The .ibd file of this database has 104857600 bytes.

After entering a bunch of rows into said table and then deleting ~150000, mariadb didn't react anymore for a while. First I thought well it has a lot to rearrange and the whole thing runs on a Raspberry II so no wonder it needs some time.
But now it reacts again and things are still weird.

What I see is

- In phpmyadmin the databases are listed in the overview.
- When I click a database I get the tables listed too, but no number in the `Rows` column and the `Collation` column says `in use` for each row.
- Clicking on a table to get the table view brings the error `Table xyz doesn't exist in engine`.
- In the databases' directories there are the files `db.opt` and for each table `tablename.frm` and `tablename.ibd`. File sizes look reasonable.
- I have stopped/started mariadb but without any change.
- top tells me there's nothing going on, so I'd say no more db housekeeping takes place right now that might be responsible for having tables "in use".

I have no idea at all what happens here. What means tables are in use? Why of all things does that appear in the Collation column? How to fix that?
There are some threads about this advising to restore a backup. I will do that if nothing else helps but first of all I would like to understand what's going on and how to avoid that in the future.

Some more information.

- version = 10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1
- I haven't changed files manually, only checked if they still exist.
- I activated the error log, restarted mariadb and found this. Nothing is added to this when I want to access tables that can't be found.

```
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.5.15 started; log sequence number 35076; transaction id 8
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230718  9:07:00
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2023-07-18  9:07:00 1 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1932: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist in engine
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2023-07-18  9:07:00 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Raspbian 11
```

Comment: What is the contents of the error log for mariadb? Which MariaDB version? Have you many changed any of the a mariadb files?

Comment: @danblack I have added more information. It's my first experience with a selfmade installation of mariadb so there might be much more information somewhere that I simply don't know about.

Comment: When you were deleting the large number of rows and MariaDB wasn't responsive, did you just let it run or did you interrupt it in some way (restarting the Pi, killing the MariaDB daemon, etc)? I wonder if the kernel resource limits killed MariaDB at some point, which would be logged somewhere (perhaps syslog or the daemon log)? Other than that, I'm hard pressed to think of a reason this would have happened.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I restartet mariadb and eventually the Pi after I found that mariadb reacts again. Who knows, perhaps this has interrupted internal cleanup actions or these actions failed because there was not enough memory. In the meantime I have set up the database anew. But nevertheless it is interesting what has happened here.

Comment: It could be that there was corruption caused when MariaDB was forced to close. As for how to recover from it, the best advice I have is to restore from a backup SQL file. Unfortunately I don't know of many other options.